# XPath not "seeing" the img element?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

Here is my html code:

```
<div style="font-size: 14px;">
    <img src="somelink.com">"TEXT"<br>
```

and here is my xpath:

```
storedText = tree.xpath('//div[@style="font-size: 14px;"]/img/text()')
```

But it doesn't seem to assign "TEXT" to storedText

EDIT: I would like to add there are html snippets that don't include img elements but text that I don't want to grab

```
<div style="font-size: 14px;">
    "TEXT I DONT WANT"
```

Comment: It doesn't look quite reliable to rely on the `style` attribute of an element. Could you show more HTML code you are dealing with? (or a link to the web-site). Thanks.

Comment: which xml package are you using? lxml, ElementTree, beautifulsoup... etc.

Comment: Try printing the `div` element to see how your html parser builds up the doc. It varies by package, but if its lxml's html parser, it would be `lxml.html.tostring(tree.xpath('//div[@style="font-size: 14px;"]')[0]`.

Comment: @alecxe heres the site: http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=2, i only want to grab team names when there is a picture (flag) next to the team name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to rely on the location of the team icon (`img` tag) and get the *following text sibling*.

Complete code using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
import lxml.html
import requests

url = 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=2'
response = requests.get(url)

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)
for item in tree.xpath('//div[@class="centerNoHeadline"]//div[@class="hotmatchbox"]//div[@class="hotmatchbox"]/div/img/following-sibling::text()'):
    print item.strip()
```

Prints:

```
LDLC
fnatic

Natus Vincere
Titan

HellRaisers
ALTERNATE

myXMG
Flipsid3
```

Answer (score 1):

`img` elements don't have included text. They are self-complete. So the text is actually part of the `div` above. Grab its text instead.

In other words:

```
storedText = tree.xpath('//div/text()')
```

As @alecxe notes, qualifying the div based on precise styling is an extremely fragile pattern. But if you want to add that or other qualifications back into the XPath expression, feel free.

Also, I assume you're using an XPath implementation that is comfortable with the vicissitudes of HTML? Some are, some aren't. But your markup snippet there, while fine for HTML, is not valid XML. If your parser / XPath combination is cool with that, you're good to go. Otherwise, you will face all manner of grief because of it.

---

**Update** Based on the new information that `lxml.html` is the parsing library: LXML doesn't use pure XPath in the same way pure XML libraries might. Instead, it's a marriage of XPath and the etree (ElementTree) API that's common to a lot of Python XML/HTML parsing libraries, salted with a handful of its own homespun approaches.

As a result, you shouldn't search directly for the `./text()` node. You should use the element's idiosyncratic `text_content()` method instead. For example:

```
import lxml.html

html = """
<div style="font-size: 14px;">
    <img src="somelink.com">"TEXT"<br>
"""

tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)

div = tree.xpath('//div[@style="font-size: 14px;"]')[0]
storedText = div.text_content()
```

Note, however, that if the XPath search does not find an element, the `[0]` indexing will fail, raising an `IndexError` exception. Somewhat less fragile is using wrapper that abstracts and handles the possibility no such node is found. For example:

```
def gettext(elist):
    if not elist or elist is None:
        return None
    return ''.join(e.text_content() for e in elist)

storedText = gettext(tree.xpath('//div[@style="font-size: 14px;"]'))
print storedText
```

With `gettext`, whether there are 0, 1, or multiple such nodes found, an appropriate value is returned.

Comment: its HTML being parsed with lxml